# wordpress - редактор - добавить class к тегу img

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

Можно ли добавить класс к тегу `img` в редакторе, при вставке изображения?

А именно через кнопку `[img]`, а не через "добавить медиа файл".

При нажатии на `[img]` мы вводим урл картинки, далее ее описания, после нажатия ок, вставляется тег такого типа

```
<img src="http://site.com/img/yourimagename.jpg" alt="YourDescription" />
```

Мне же нужно сделать так, чтобы при нажатии ок, было все тоже самое, кроме автоматически добавленного класса.

К примеру

```
<img class="left" src="http://site.com/img/yourimagename.jpg" alt="YourDescription" />
```

Нужен именно такой метод.

Comment: Что вам мешает создать собственную кнопку и повесить на нее все, что угодно? Я же вам отвечал на вопрос, как это сделать.

Comment: гуглояндексы за 2 сек. выдадут 1005000 рецептов как добавить кнопку в редактор. Тут мало того, что гуглить лень, так на этот вопрос уже отвечали. Неужто настолько уже лень одолела?

Comment: Зачем мне создавать новую кнопку, если уже есть таковая, причем с promt строкой. Я просто думал сделать проще, добавить к ней класс, и все готово. А не делать еще одну кнопку такого же типа, только с классом.

Comment: Это - не проще. Более того, невозможно без правки скрипта в ядре: /wp-includes/js/quicktags.js. Там в строках 646-665 расписан callback при нажатии на кнопку img. Ничего, кроме ссылки и описания, он вставлять не умеет, никаких хуков в нем нет. Надо делать свою кнопку по образу и подобию img.

Comment: Спасибо, просто не хотел изобретать велосипед, но как оказалось придеться.